# Issues connection to Ubuntu via PuTTy

Tags: windows, ubuntu, ssh, putty

I'm not sure this is the appropriate stack exchange site to post this question on. If not, please flag this for migration.

I am trying to use PuTTy ssh into my ubuntu machine which is wirelessly connected to the same network. I originally ran `ifconfig` to get my ubuntu machines private network IP address. I then verified that ssh was running, I even ssh'd into my school network and then into the ubuntu machine itself. No problems yet.

On my windows 8 machine I ran `ipconfig` to get my private network IPv4 address. I then pinged my ubunty machines IP and 100% of packets were received. I figured, "OK we are ready to use PuTTy to connect to my Ubuntu Machine". Keep in mind this was my first time using PuTTy. I tried entering the IP of my ubuntu machine in the PuTTy Config GUI but I got a connection timeout. At this moment I don't really know what's going on, SSH is running on port 22 of my Ubuntu machine and I can ping the machine why is it not connecting? (I tried [username]@ip too).

So I went on my Ubuntu machine and ran nmap -sP 192.168.0.1/24 and found that my windows machines IP did not show up, the host is down. I'm at a lost in something I am not very familiar with. Would anyone be able to help me or direct me to some resources that would trouble shoot my problem?

Thank you

EDIT (ADDITION):
tyler@tyler-Aspire-5250:~$ nmap -v 192.168.0.123

Starting Nmap 6.40 ( http://nmap.org ) at 2014-06-06 01:56 MDT
Initiating Ping Scan at 01:56
Scanning 192.168.0.123 [2 ports]
Completed Ping Scan at 01:56, 3.00s elapsed (1 total hosts)
Nmap scan report for 192.168.0.123 [host down]
Read data files from: /usr/bin/../share/nmap
Note: Host seems down. If it is really up, but blocking our ping probes, try -Pn
Nmap done: 1 IP address (0 hosts up) scanned in 3.14 seconds
tyler@tyler-Aspire-5250:~$ nmap -Pn 192.168.0.123

Starting Nmap 6.40 ( http://nmap.org ) at 2014-06-06 01:56 MDT
Nmap scan report for 192.168.0.123
Host is up (0.022s latency).
Not shown: 998 filtered ports
PORT     STATE SERVICE
2869/tcp open  icslap
5357/tcp open  wsdapi

Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 72.51 seconds

Comment: Please try connecting with the *-v* option: it increases the verbosity. Then post the results here.

Comment: @MariusMatutiae I've added the the output above

Answer (score 0):

The output of *nmap* you posted does not help me much, the post I asked for would be more conclusive. Yet the presence of 998 filtered ports suggests, without truly establishing, the presence of a firewall. So what I can suggest is that you check your own Windows firewall, trying to establish whether outgoing connections on port 22 are allowed.

If they are blocked, then this is *surely* the root cause of your problems: you should allow *ssh* connections, *i.e.* those occurring on port TCP-22.

Comment: My apologies Marius, I thought that was what you were asking for. I believe it might have to do with my windows firewall. When I get back home from work I will set new rules to allow outgoing connections on port 22 and report back